# Null Pointer - Timer + Array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, timer, null

I have discovered were the error was, was declaring the array as laneCar[] in one part of my code and laneCars[] elsewhere which was causing null pointer errors.

Comment: save yourself a lot of trouble and just use an `ArrayList`

Comment: Please do not edit out your question when you have solved it, this prevents others from learning from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're initialising the arrays *within* your population loop e.g.

```
for (int r = 0; r < 13; r++)
{ 
    roadLane[] lanes = new roadLane[13];
    // ...
```

and so each time through the loop you create a new array and then populate a *single* element within it. All the other elements will be null.

You likely need to do this *first* e.g.

```
roadLane[] lanes = new roadLane[13];
for (int r = 0; r < 13; r++)
{ 
    // ...
```

Comment: the roadLane array is fine, (and works perfectly). I having issues with the array of laneCars. I can create and populate the array fine - its when I attempt to "animate" the array objects with the timer that I'm receiving null pointer errors 

I do however see your point - it seems like a waste of cycles to initialising the array within the loop - i've now moved both instances of this outside of the loop (still receiving errors on the  timer updates however)